# What is document.poppedLayer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
if (browserType == "gecko" )
document.poppedLayer =
eval('document.getElementById("realtooltip")');
else if (browserType == "ie")
document.poppedLayer =
eval('document.getElementById("realtooltip")');
else
document.poppedLayer =
eval('document.layers["realtooltip"]');
document.poppedLayer.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

poppedLayer is used in above code, I want to understand what is poppedLayer? If someone can give me reference of the documentation about it.

Comment: I would love to know where you got this code from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a custom variable, placed on the document object (not a recommended practice).

It's being used as a pointer to this 'realtooltip' element.